# VS22 WCF Web Service reference - automatically edit output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I have a connected service that creates the models and the web client for a soap 1.1 API of a paid product I use:

```
{
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://service.de/atc/webservices?wsdl"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2",
      "System.Collections.Generic.List`1"
    ],
    "messageContract": true,
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, ServiceReference1"
    ],
    "references": [
      "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common, 4.7.0}",
      "System.Buffers, {System.Buffers, 4.5.1}",
      "System.Collections.Immutable, {System.Collections.Immutable, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Memory, {System.Memory, 4.5.5}",
      "System.Numerics.Vectors, {System.Numerics.Vectors, 4.4.0}",
      "System.Reflection.Metadata, {System.Reflection.Metadata, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, {System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 6.0.0}",
      "System.ServiceModel, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Duplex, {System.ServiceModel.Duplex, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Http, {System.ServiceModel.Http, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, {System.ServiceModel.NetTcp, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, {System.ServiceModel.Primitives, 4.4.4}",
      "System.ServiceModel.Security, {System.ServiceModel.Security, 4.4.4}",
      "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, {System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, 7.0.0}",
      "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, {System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, 4.5.4}",
      "System.Web.Services.Description, {System.Web.Services.Description, 6.0.0}"
    ],
    "targetFramework": "netstandard2.1",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

The problem is, that everything is put into one file and I want to separate the models and the logic (the web client). How can I achieve this?

Also, all models and operations are named in camel case. How can I automatically change the operation methods, the models, and their properties to pascal case?

Comment: *How can I automatically change...* you can't ... this code is generated by (dotnet-)svcutil and you have little to do about it ... you can "fix" generated code "by hand"  (and do this again when wsdl would change in the future :D)

Comment: See following to add a reference (it is not automatic)  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022#to-add-a-reference-to-a-service-in-the-current-solution-net-framework-projects

Comment: @jdweng it would create the same code

Comment: Would it be possible to do it with a source generator that reads in the generated cs using `System.CodeDom` and writes it to actual files within different projects and not just using `context.AddSource`